# Git: Combining git-flow with forking workflow?

Tags: git, git-flow

The previous days I read https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow to which I have a a question:

Is there a viable reason to combine the Gitflow Workflow and the Forking Workflow for a project and if so how would one do that in a useful manner?

Answer (score 2):

The combination of the  the Gitflow Workflow and the Forking Workflow is very useful.

Each user works in own Fork. If some commit is ready for the develop/master/gold branch, the user do a pull from the fork to common branch.

And will be cool if only Team Lead(or any other senior) will have permission to merge the pull to the main branch. All others are working with forks only.

Also is useful to setup automatic sync from the main branch (develop/master/gold) to the local forks.

Comment: What is a Gold branch?

Comment: develop, master, gold - it is just names for a branch with clean code

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. However I am not sure I get what you mean in total. What do you mean with "common branch"? Do you mean a local feature branch? Also, in the gitflow workflow (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), develop and master/gold are two very distinct branches. Your answer is not so clear, yet. Maybe you can give some more details in your answer - that would be great!

Comment: In terms of the article (nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model) this branch is calling develop. Will be comfortable to setup synchronization of develop with each local fork.

Comment: Example: if some commit was merged in develop, then all local fork will be updated by this commit. It is very useful. Everybody will have last code in their local forks.